# React Native BluetoothManager NativeModules NULL

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to use BluetoothManager in React Native, already did these steps:

- I did fresh install with `react-native init MyProject`
- Imported NativeMoludes in App.js: `import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, ScrollView, View, Text, StatusBar, NativeModules } from 'react-native';`
- Initialized BluetoothManager: `const { BluetoothManager} = NativeModules;`
- And do `alert(BluetoothManager);` before `return(...)`

but it always alerts null. Did I miss something in the RN installation or the import?
I'm using React Native v.0.62.2. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager or https://github.com/Polidea/react-native-ble-plx for everything bluetooth related in react-native

Answer (score 0):

You are `not importing BluetoothManager properly`, You have to install this module,

https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager

Link that module(if the auto-linking is not available but or pod install in the case of ios) with your project and then import like below

```
import BleManager from 'react-native-ble-manager';
```

Also here is an example of import and usage too.

https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager/blob/master/example/App.js